# Black screen when try to capture Vive gameplay using VRCapture

Tags: unity, htc-vive, game-recording, gameplay3d-engine

I'm using Unity, the first recording in VR Mode was fine. Then the rest were just black screen. No errors were detected and my gameplay was just playing fine. Also the red dot recording signal on Vive HMD was not there anymore. Any advice ?

Setting :

========VRCapture Diagnosis========

Software Checksum: 37CD Version: 1.0.278.128
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Display Card: GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 64 Bit
VR Headset: HTC Vive MV
Microphone: Microphone (2- USB Audio Device)

Comment: I am having the same problem on different hardware
The thing that is the same it that we are both running Unity and VRCapture ========VRCapture Diagnosis======== Software Checksum: 8A9B
Version: 1.0.278.128
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz
Display Card: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 64 Bit VR Headset: Oculus Rift CV1
Microphone: Microphone (Rift Audio)

Answer (score 1):

apologies for adding to the question yesterday.

I have found a solution to make sample videos.
It is not as cool as VRCapture, but it works for both video and audio.

I downloaded http://camstudio.org/ for free and changed the video settings
    options -> video options -> compressor
        to IYUV

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I'm still using VRCapture tho..   
When my VRcapture isn't working in Unity scene, I export my scene and then play it and capture it using VRCapture again. One of these methods is working. Sometime directly capturing from Unity is working, sometimes I need to export my scene, I just change it to where it works.